# Overlay image on another image opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images in which one is smaller and another one is bigger. I want to overlay the object in a smaller image (transparent background) to the larger one but turns out it has the black dotted lines at the border of overlay objects. I did google search and found this [overlay image on another image with opencv and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620706/overlay-image-on-another-image-with-opencv-and-numpy) but still, it has the problem that I mentioned above. Any idea for a better overlaying method? Thanks in advance.

Code (For example):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("dark_background")
img1 = cv2.imread("src/img1.jpg",-1)
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.png",-1) # rgba picture
h, w, c = img2.shape

img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (w, h), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
result = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)


alpha = img2[:, :, 3] / 255.0
result[:, :, 0] = (1. - alpha) * img1[:, :, 0] + alpha * img2[:, :, 0]
result[:, :, 1] = (1. - alpha) * img1[:, :, 1] + alpha * img2[:, :, 1]
result[:, :, 2] = (1. - alpha) * img1[:, :, 2] + alpha * img2[:, :, 2]
result = cv2.resize(result, (1000,720))
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

img1:
[image]

img2:
[image]

Output (As you can see, there is some black dotted lines at the border of the overlay objects):

[image]

Comment: you draw `img_B`, right? then draw it with alpha channel. problem doesn't even happen then.

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Unfortunately, it didn't work also. The black dotted lines still exist. I have edited the code for the rgba image.

Comment: unfortunately, that's still rgba derived from plain rgb, where you mask out the background color. just say that you *didn't* draw that user interface yourself. -- now, what you need is to *erode* the alpha channel. just a `cv2.erode` call with `None` kernel and one iteration should see improvement

Comment: Yes, indeed the result is better and quite satisfactory. Thanks for that!